# Java applet and their future?

Tags: java, applet

As i am working in government project and they are telling us to be use Java Applet for their website like lots of bank website uses for login. Is this a good idea to use Java Applet? As we have lots of good framework like **JSF**, **Struts** ,**Zk** etc. Still Applet give us advantage in any context if yes please let me know.

Comment: This answer will be closed as it is primarily opinion based.

Comment: In my personal opinion, Applet is the worst part of Java [Strictly my view]

Comment: @reddy but why banks used them as you are indian lots of govt. banks used them in their website for login sorry but i do not want to disclose the name of banks.

Comment: I haven't seen any indian bank is using Applets. They are using either Struts/Spring or JSF. Personally I knew few of the banking companies code base

Comment: Agree but i saw that ,thats why i asked

Comment: All I can say, tell them that Struts/Spring is the more advanced and secure and convince them. You can find why advance by bing it.

Remember every job can be done by any framework/language. It's all about how secure and effectively you can make it so that maintenance will be less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

applets will give you a java UI inside a browser, but they are crippled for security reasons and also most of the java security vulnerabilities discovered are usually around the applet area.

using [java web-start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) will give you a web-launched (from clickable link) full-blown java application with less security restrictions and less security vulnerabilities to be worried about, while not requiring anything special on user's machines (you need java installed on users machines for both applets and web-start to work).

so, in my opinion, web-start simply makes applets obsolete.

Comment: If applet have security issue why bank online banking website used them?

Comment: @subodhjoshi - because they tend to be conservative and applets have been around for far longer than web-start.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your this comment ?

Comment: @subodhjoshi - whats to elaborate? applets are very old technology and theyve been there since the early days of java. webstart is more recent (came out with java 1.4) and banks dont really have a reputation for using bleeding-edge technologies :-) they usually just dont touch anything that they manage to make work.